# Converting pressure to voltage

Tags: voltage, sensor, adc, pressure

I am using an ifm PN2028 sensor and my sensor gives me an reading in mbar. Measuring range of the sensor is -12.5 to 250 mbar.

The output of the sensor is analogue signal (4...20mA or 0..10V). The output is having a linear relationship.

How would the reading of mbar be converted in mA or V?

Comment: `my sensor gives me an output in mbar.` ... mbar is not an electrical quantity ... what does the sensor output electrically?

Comment: @jsotola I mean to say my sensor gives me a reading i.e. displayed on the sensor in mbar.

Comment: that clarifies what you mean, but does not answer my question ... the clarification should be done to your question ... the answer to my question should also be added to your question

Comment: The actual pressure sensor itself has to be doing one of (a) Outputting a varying voltage, (b) Outputting a varying current or (c) Presenting a varying resistance. Only way forward is to resolve which one and what each level or the varying parameter represents. Also need to know if the output is linear or not over its range.

Comment: @ Michael Karas @jsotola The output of the sensor is analogue signal (4...20mA or 0..10V). The output is having a linear relationship.

Comment: @NehalTrivedi this information does not belong in a comment ... it belongs in the question at top of this page ... please edit your question

Comment: @NehalTrivedi this site is not a forum ... it is a question and answer site ... the question at top of this page should be self contained ... the question's clarity should not depend on information in comments

Comment: @MichaelKaras ... another possibility ...  (d) Presenting a varying signal frequency

Comment: The manufacturer has chosen a relation between pressure and voltage. Either you find it in the datasheet or empiric by measurement.

Comment: Here's [the datasheet](https://www.ifm.com/restservices/de/en/assets/c3VwcGxpZXJzL2lmbS9kb2N1bWVudHMvcHJvZHVjdC9QTjIwMjgtMDEvZGF0ZW5ibGFldHRlci9QTjIwMjgtMDFfRU4tVVMucGRm). The device appears to be already capable of either 0-10 V or 4-20 mA output (it says it is configurable.) This really seems to be a "user issue" for the manufacturer. Clearly, the OP wants something and doesn't understand how to get it. Perhaps just an expression -- as I've known people who cannot even work out how to apply a % calculation. It's a high-end sensor product and the manufacturer should be able to help with that.

Comment: @jsotola have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: it looks like the sensor already outputs the `Desired output would be 0-10 V.` ........... now it is unclear what you are asking ... `Can anyone guide me how this can be calculated?` ... what do you want to calculate?

Comment: @jsotola does my question make sense now?

Comment: yes, it does ... your question is purely mathematic ... it has nothing to do with electronics .... think about it ... `-12.5 to 250 mbar` equals `0 V to 10 V` and the relationship is linear

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to calculate anything. You need to read the manual as Jonk said and set the parameter OU2 to voltage and measure the voltage between pin 2 and 3. The parameters AES and AEP sets the start (AEP) and end (AEP) of the measurement range but is defult full scale (I think).